# Get Last NID into Variable

Tags: nodes

I need to get the previous (referrer) NID into a variable on a page. After saving new content of a certain content type a rule will redirect the visitor to a set page where I would like to have the NID of the new node to play with. Can anyone point me in the right direction? I think its possibly going to be one of those ones that you'd think is simple but ends up being awfully complex but I'm really in need of a solution and can't find anything very relevant.

Thanks in advance folks!

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to create a rule based on this:

1. event: After content has been saved...
2. condition:  content is new
3. condition:  content is type (select type)
4. action: page redirect:  fill in page here with tokens based up content above

In the page direct you can create a query variable after the ?, eg foo=[TOKEN], and then in your page, you can access that variable via $_GET['foo'] or $_REQUEST['foo'].

Comment: Good thinking Jimajamma! Thanks for the super quick response.

Comment: ps. I just tried it and it works a bloomin' treat, thanks again!

Comment: my pleasure, quite welcome!